# Do I need to create my own ExecutorService when implementinf AsyncProcessors in Camel

Tags: asynchronous, apache-camel

I am working on a Camel route that needs to execute a piece of logic in a separate thread. 
Basically, I have a buffer that I get both an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` from. I want to write to the `OutputStream` in a separate thread, and set the `InputStream` as the body and return immediately. I am looking into `AsyncProcessor`, but it seems all it provides is a callback to notify when done, which leaves an option to run asynchronously but no actual mechanism to do so. I can surely have my own `ExecutorService` and run with that, but could it be that this gigantic machinery that is Camel has no built-in facility for this? The skimpy text on the topic available on the Camel site says almost nothing on *how* is one supposed to implement asynchronous execution.

**UPDATE:** I documented what I ended up doing [here](http://thatjavathing.blogspot.nl/2014/09/how-to-make-asynchronous-processor-in.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its a callback, and how you call this is up to component developers, often a 3rd party library that the Camel component leverages has already some async engine, that its just a matter of integrate with.

If you build your own component without such async engine, you can use a thread pool. There is a executor service manager api from CamelContext that can be a good idea to use as it helps managing the thread pool and expose details about it at runtime.

You can find more details here:

- http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html
- http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html

And if you have Camel in Action book, then chapter 10 covers this, and section 10.6 how to write a custom component with async processing.

Comment: The book was a great tip!